# Some archive by year page return 404

Tags: archives, 404-error, breadcrumb

When clicking on archive in my wordpress blog I get a list with links to different month, e.g.,

October 2020, ..., June 2019, ...

When clicking on a month I get a view with posts whichs were published in this month and the breadcrumb creates a link to the respective year. While all year-links work, the link for 2019 return 404.
I have no idea where to start to fix this error. Do you have an idea why I get 404 for this specific year?

Comment: Is this a WordPress 404 or an Apache/Nginx 404? Is the issue specifically with the breadcrumb link? How is the breadcrumb implemented? Is it a theme feature?

Comment: It's a WordPress 404 error. Yes it's specifically in the breadcrumb. It appears only when I go to "archive" and then chose a for example "June 2019". Then on the "June 2019" archive page there appears a link to the overview page of the "2019" archive. And this 2019 archive page return a 404 error. It happens only with the 2019 archive. There is not problem with other years.

Comment: Are there posts for 2019 in the system?

Comment: Yes the 2019 posts are working without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to make sure the folder structure is correct in your WordPress installation? A 404 error is caused if the URL does not point to a valid area. So if the URL is yourwebsite/2019/04/myblogname - and a 404 error appears - it means there is no file with that name.

A few ways to approach this.

Something is wrong with your permalink structure. In Setting -> Permalink. Enter in there and just click 'save' to refresh your permalink structure.

Also, while you are here...what is your permalink structure look like? Did you change it? Perhaps those posts are no longer at the example (/2019/04/myblogpost). Check out the setting for permalink here: https://wordpress.org/support/article/settings-permalinks-screen/

I would say, that the links on your archive are inaccurate. Try finding out where a 2019 blog post is located at. If you changed the permalink structure and the option you picked is /yourwebsite/myblogpost, that means /blog/2019/04/myblogpost no longer exists and you will get a 404 error.

I believe your issue is related to the permalink settings you choose. If it looks right, reset the settings (by just saving and WordPress will rebuild it).

So, 1. Your links in the archive are pointing to old file locations or 2. Your permalink settings are off (or need to be reset).

One of these will most likely be your issue.

Comment: There's no such folder (directory) as /blog/. You might want to look into WordPress's template hierarchy.

Comment: @vancoder Wops, you are right. I updated my response. Thanks for noticing that.

Comment: The problem ist that `blog/2018` works but `/blog/2019` does not. So there should be no problems since `/blog/2018` works and I have no idea why one special year is not working.

Comment: @methus I updated my answer to assist you. It's somethink to do with your permalink settings, it's handed by WordPress core.